# Bash: Comparing ip addresses in two variables

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have two bash variables

```
$checkVar = 10.10.10.111 10.10.10.112 10.10.10.117
$Server = 10.10.10.114 10.10.10.112 10.10.10.113 10.10.10.111
```

I want to make my test as `PASS` if ONLY first 2 values in `$checkVar` are present in `$Server` 
In above example, the test should `PASS` because first 2 values in `$checkVar` `10.10.10.111 10.10.10.112` are present in `$Server`

I have written the below logic but it is not working

```
if [[ ${checkVar%%,*} = *"$Server"* ]]; then 
    test=pass
else
    test=fail
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `if` statement, `${checkVar%%,*}` returns a value of `$checkVar` with a comma and the trailing characters deleted, which may not be what you want because `$checkVar` does not contain commas at all.
In addition, `*"$Server"*` expression just returns a string with literal asterisks appended to `$Server` at the leading and trailing positions without expanding anything. You'll see the comparison of these expressions does not make sense.

Try instead something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

checkVar="10.10.10.111 10.10.10.112 10.10.10.117"
Server="10.10.10.114 10.10.10.112 10.10.10.113 10.10.10.111"

set -- $checkVar
if [[ " $Server " =~ [[:blank:]]$1[[:blank:]] && " $Server " =~ [[:blank:]]$2[[:blank:]] ]]; then
    test=pass
else
    test=fail
fi
echo "$test"
```

where $1 holds the 1st value in $checkVar and $2 does the 2nd.
In the `if` statement, the regular expression tests if both $1 and $2 exist and each are surrounded by spaces.